# How to display json value in django template?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

This is my View.py code...

```
import requests 
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.shortcuts import render import json 
def book(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://api.railwayapi.com/cancelled/date/01-09-2016/apikey/mezxa1595/', params=request.POST)
        book=r.json()
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://api.railwayapi.com/cancelled/date/01-09-2016/apikey/mezxa1595/', params=request.GET)
        book=r.json()
        js=json.dumps(book)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return render(request,'book.html', {'js':js})
    return HttpResponse('Could not save data')
```

and question is that how to display `return render(request,'book.html', {'js':js})` in Html?

Comment: Could you fix code formatting to improve readability?

Comment: you have to write book.html file.

Comment: follow the django-tutorial then you will find out.

Answer (score -1):

That "js" should be a python dict not json object. You may need to:

```
return render(request,'book.html', {'js': json.loads(js)})
```

Then you can use the variables in `book.html` template.

Comment: Requests returns a Python dict from the`json()` method.